# How to Get Children From StackLayout By Datatype?

Tags: c#, xamarin

i have a stacklayout which contains a long list of children with different Views,as in images,Labels etc.

```
namespace bizclos1{
  public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Button SaveLabel= new Button();
    public Button SaveImage = new Button();
    public StackLayout TotalStackLayout = new StackLayout();

    public Page1 ()
    {
        SaveLabel.Clicked += SaveLabel_Clicked;
        SaveImage.Clicked += SaveImage_Clicked;
        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                SaveImage,
                SaveLabel,
                TotalStackLayout
            }
        };
    }

    private void SaveImage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image IMG = new Image();
        TotalStackLayout.Children.Add(IMG);
    }

    private void SaveLabel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label LBL = new Label();
        TotalStackLayout.Children.Add(LBL);
    }
}
```

}

**First question**

i would like to know if its possible to select only the Labels and if it is how can i do that?

**second question**

also how do i select a child of a particular index, as in child of index 4?

Comment: What do you mean by "datatype"?  A StackLayout's children are all Views - they don't have any inherent notion of datatype.  It would be helpful if you included the relevant code where you are building the layout.

Comment: Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18599/visual-tree-helper

Comment: @Jason i edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `LINQ` to select just the `Label` elements

```
using System.Linq;

var labels = TotalStackLayout.Children.Where(x => x is Label).ToList();
```

to select an element by index

```
var item = TotalStackLayout.Children[4];
```

Comment: Thanks,this is the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Beautiful answer! +1 for the `is`